# best way to write to Azure Blob Storage highly concurrently?

Tags: azure, concurrency, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions

what is the best way to write to Azure Blob Storage highly concurrently, for example in an Azure Cloud Function?
I am using an Append Blob already as this is supposed to be the way.
Order of writes are not important for me.

I tried the following so far:

- I used the API method *BlobService.appendBlobFromText* without any access conditions -> this seems to skip writes. I ran a concurrent test and ca. 6000 of 40000 writes didn't end up in the final blob
- I tried *BlobService.appendBlobFromText with Access Condition etag* -> this resulted in lots of failed writes. But it seems like this solution breaks down in terms of performance, plus I had a file afterwards with many duplicated writes.
- I wanted to use a Function Output Binding but this was not an option due to requirements in how to format and name the output blob

Edit:

this is currently the code I currently implemented to write the CSV blob. The function is triggered by a Queue message:

```
module.exports = function (context, myQueueItem) {
  context.log(
    'JavaScript queue trigger function processed work item',
    myQueueItem
  )

  let blobService = storage.createBlobService(config.targetBlobConnection)
  let messageDayString = csvTransformer.determineDayFromMessage(myQueueItem)
  let blobName = messageDayString + '.csv'
  let csvMessage
  async.waterfall(
    [
      function (callback) {
        blobService.createContainerIfNotExists(
          config.targetBlobContainer,
          { publicAccessLevel: 'blob' },
          err => {
            callback(err)
          }
        )
      },
      function (callback) {
        blobService.doesBlobExist(
          config.targetBlobContainer,
          blobName,
          null,
          (err, blobResult) => {
            context.log('got blobResult: ', blobResult)
            callback(err, blobResult)
          }
        )
      },
      function (blobResult, callback) {
        if (blobResult && blobResult.exists) {
          csvMessage = csvTransformer.transformMessageToCSV(myQueueItem, false)
          blobService.appendBlockFromText(
            config.targetBlobContainer,
            blobName,
            '\n' + csvMessage,
            {accessConditions:
              {EtagMatch: '*'
              }
            },
            (err, appendedBlobResult) => {
              context.log('appended to existing blob: ', appendedBlobResult)
              callback(err, appendedBlobResult)
            }
          )
        } else {
          csvMessage = csvTransformer.transformMessageToCSV(myQueueItem, true)
          blobService.createAppendBlobFromText(
            config.targetBlobContainer,
            blobName,
            csvMessage,
            {accessConditions:
              {EtagNonMatch: '*'
              }
            },
            (err, createdBlobResult) => {
              context.log('created new blob: ', createdBlobResult)
              callback(err, blobResult)
            }
          )
        }
      }
    ],
    function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        context.log.error('Error happened!')
        context.log.error(err)
        context.done(err)
      } else {
        context.log('appended CSV message to blob')
        context.bindings.outputQueueItem = csvMessage
        context.done()
      }
    }
  )
}
```

Here is a sample message:

```
{
  "Currency": "GBP",
  "StorefrontId": "BB64522",
  "VendorID": "",
  "BackendId": "210be438-2e5f-428d-bd43-3066f1b7bc22",
  "TransactionDateTime": "1\/28\/2018 3:35:54 PM",
  "SubscriberType": "Standard",
  "TransactionType": "Sale",
  "PartitionKey": "WholesaleTransaction",
  "RowKey": "16626034"
}
```

I want to transform each message into CSV using my library, each appended into a blob named after the day of the transaction. The message above would go into a Blob named 2018-28-01.csv

Comment: what are you trying to do ? do you really need to write in the same blobl ? what do you mean by `I wanted to use a Function Output Binding but this was not an option due to requirements in how to format and name the output blob` ? I did some functions with blob output with really custom and specific name format

Comment: I want to name the blobs based on message content. Specifically, I want to create 1 blob bucket per day, based on a date field in the given messges

Comment: @sebbulon, if you can manage to attach that message content metadata in something that is accessible to a binding expression, you could still use it to manipulate the name. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#binding-expressions-and-patterns.

Comment: Could you show us a sample of the message the function receive ? Is it an http trigger ? a service bus trigger ? Could you share some code you tried so far

Comment: I added code and sample message

Comment: @Thomas this dynamic binding seems to be only available when implementing the function in C#, still outstanding for JavaScript - accoding to https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/85